# No match for custom hashing / equals function with an unordered_map

Tags: c++, hash, equals, unordered-map

I have the following code.

file `Ant.h`

```
class hashing_func {
    public:
        unsigned long operator()(const Node& key) const {
            unsigned long hash;
            hash = key.GetId();
            return hash;
        }
};

class key_equal_fn {
    public:
        bool operator()(const Node& t1, const Node& t2) const {
            return (t1.GetId() == t2.GetId());
        }
};

class Ant {
    private:
        std :: unordered_map <Node*, int, hashing_func, key_equal_fn> nodemap;
};
```

However, on compiling, I keep getting the error message

```
[Error] no match for call to '(const hashing_func)(Node* const&)'
```

Obviously, my map contains `Node*` (node-pointers) as keys, and currently expects

```
long unsigned int hashing_func :: operator() ( const Node& const)
```

How would I go about to fix this (convert the hashing and equal function to accept Node-pointers)? Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your keys are `Node*`, but your hash and equality comparator are for `const Node&`. You would need to use `Node` keys, or write functors for `Node*`:

```
std :: unordered_map <Node, int, hashing_func, key_equal_fn> nodemap;
```

or

```
class hashing_func 
{
    public:
        unsigned long operator()(const Node* key) const 
        {
            return = key->GetId();
        }
};
```

etc.

Comment: `const Node*` wouldn't work, the pointer is const, not what it points to.

Comment: My bad, I forgot another `const` in my test for `GetId()`. You are right that it would work. +1

Comment: I just figured that instead of `const Node* key`, `Node* const& key` works as well. Could you please explain why this is?

Comment: @bas probably because `GetId()` has not been marked as a `const` method (I would bet that it should be). `const Node*` is a non-const pointer to a `const` `Node`, meaning you cannot modify the `Node`. `Node* const&` is a reference to a `const` pointer to a non-`const` node, meaninf you pass the pointer by reference but cannot modify it, but you *can* modify the `Node` it points to. Hash and logical comparisons that modify their arguments are not a good idea.

Comment: @bas It passes a reference to the pointer stored in the unordered map. In fact that is what is the generic pattern you need: `KeyType const&` - where `KeyType` in your case is `Node*`. Using `Node*` instead is shorter and in this case does not have any drawbacks, `const Node*` is actually adding `const` to the node that the pointer points to, so it slightly chances the semantics.

Answer (score 2):

For the hash, the signature should be

```
unsigned long operator()(Node* key) const;
```

and for the comparison, it should be

```
bool operator()(Node* t1, Node* t2) const;
```